# RegisterMany does not register all interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dryioc

I am using DryIoc and this is my first experience with a dependency injection framework. Basically I need to register all classes implementing IService as singleton. Of every IService implementation I need to register also all other interfaces. I would like to do that with a single instruction.
So my first try was:

```
container.RegisterMany<IService>(Reuse.Singleton);
```

I receive *DryIoc.ContainerException Registering abstract implementation type IService when it is should be concrete. Also there is not FactoryMethod to use instead*

After some googling I found:

```
 container.RegisterMany(new[] { typeof(IService).Assembly }, type => type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IService)),
            Reuse.Singleton, FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments);
```

But

```
resolver.ResolveMany<IOtherInterface>();
```

returns empty enumeration.

If I register every single implementation like

```
container.RegisterMany<Service1>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.RegisterMany<Service2>(Reuse.Singleton);
...
```

all works, but I suppose there is a way to do that without writing a single register for every service implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It is  not working because you are filtering service types (interfaces) instead of implementation types.

Try this:

```
container.RegisterMany(
    typeof(IService).Assembly.GetLoadedTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IService))),
    t => t.IsInterface, …);
```

Comment: I cannot find a constructor to add Reuse.Singleton that does not raise DryIoc.ContainerException Registering abstract implementation ...

Comment: > constructor to add `Reuse.Singleton` ?

Comment: Sbstract class cannot be registered as implementation, cause it not something you can create in c#. But it can be registered as service type for implenting non-abstract class.

Comment: I do not have abstract classes... Anyway I am using now container.RegisterMany<Service1>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.RegisterMany<Service2>(Reuse.Singleton); and container.ResolveMany<IService>(); returns both singletons despite the fact in the [doc](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RegisterResolve) I read _X, Y, A are sharing the same singleton_

Comment: The same single `RegisterMany` guaranties the same singleton. Otherwise if you have a multiple Register.., use `RegisterMapping` which is also in the docs.